# Trying to test my nest api with jest, returns undefined

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am attempting to create a Jest test with the NestJs framework.

The test should check the controller and service however 1) The controller is undefined and 2) The service is undefined.

Here is the code in my **home-cards.controller.spec.ts**:

```js
describe('HomeCardsController', () => {
    let homeCardsController: HomeCardsController;
    let homeCardsService: HomeCardsService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([HomeCard])],
            controllers: [HomeCardsController],
            providers: [HomeCardsService]
        }).compile();

        homeCardsController = module.get<HomeCardsController>(HomeCardsController);
        homeCardsService = module.get<HomeCardsService>(HomeCardsService);
    });

    describe('findall', () => {
        it('should return an array of home cards', async () => {
            expect( await homeCardsController.findAll(1000)).toBeInstanceOf(Array);
        });
    });
});
```

errors:

New error as controller asking for user:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientId' of undefined

      17 |   async findAll(@Req() request): Promise<HomeCard[]> {
      18 |       const user: AuthUser = request.user;
    > 19 |       return await this.homeCardsService.findAll(user.clientId);
         |                                                       ^
      20 |   }
      21 | 
      22 |   @Get(":id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock method of HomeCardsService that is called to HomeCardsController

```js
import { HomeCardService } from './home-cards.service.ts'; // your path to service
jest.mock('./home-cards.service.ts'); // your path to service

describe('HomeCardsController', () => {
    let homeCardsController: HomeCardsController;
    let homeCardsService: HomeCardsService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            // imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([HomeCard])], <- unit test don't need database, mock all
            controllers: [HomeCardsController],
            providers: [HomeCardsService]
        }).compile();

        homeCardsController = module.get<HomeCardsController>(HomeCardsController);
        homeCardsService = module.get<HomeCardsService>(HomeCardsService);
    });

    describe('findall', () => {
        it('should return an array of home cards', async () => {
            const result = []; // some result for mock method
            jest.spyOn(homeCardsService, 'findAll').mockImplementation(() => result);
            const request = {user: {clientId: 1000}}
            expect( await homeCardsController.findAll(request)).toBeInstanceOf(Array);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I now get this error. I have updated the question

Comment: and you should not add imports to module for unit tests

Comment: So I've added your suggestion and that works, but jest is not mocking the controller properly? I am not sure. I have added the error in the question again. The controller is trying to get a user object with a client ID but as I have not made a request it is undefined. How do I mock this part of the request?

Comment: Request object must be passed to the controller.

Comment: Okay I have done that - all working, thanks. Also, does a jest test query the database? So my find all method is currently returning an array of length 0 but it should contain data. Do I have to mock the response also? If so what is the point of testing if I am just mocking everything? Just to test business logic? Thanks

Comment: Yes, unit tests are just to test business logic, but you can write e2e test. https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
expect( await homeCardsController.findAll(1000)).toBeInstanceOf(Array);
```

You have put value **1000** instead of request @Req which should be following object:

```
const request = {
  user: {
    clientId: 1000
  }
}
expect( await homeCardsController.findAll(request)).toBeInstanceOf(Array);
```

If you wish you can mock your repository like this (syntax in braces below HomeCardsService):

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
    controllers: [HomeCardsController],
    providers: [
      HomeCardsService,
      {
        provide: getRepositoryToken(HomeCard),
        useValue: jest.fn(() => ({
        save: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        createQueryBuilder: jest.fn(() => ({
          select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          getOne: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(someMockedValue),
        })),
        }))(),
      },
    ]
  }).compile();
```